# Web scraping a table through multiple pages with a single link

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape a table on a webpage as part of an assignment using Python. I want to scrape all 618 records of the table which are scattered across 13 pages in the same URL. However, my program only scrapes the first page of the table and its records. The URL is in my code, which can be found below:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
import requests as r

base_URL = 'https://www.nba.com/players' 

def scrape_webpage(URL):
  player_names = []
  page = r.get(URL)
  print(f'{page.status_code}')
  soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser') 
  raw_player_names = soup.find_all('div', class_='flex flex-col lg:flex-row')
  for name in raw_player_names:
    player_names.append(name.get_text().strip())
  print(player_names) 

scrape_webpage(base_URL)
```

Comment: That means you have to examine the web page HTML and figure out what happens when you request the next page.  You'll then need to make another request to get the next page.

Comment: It looks like the navigation is all done in Javascript.  Have you clicked "next page" and watched the results in the "Developer Tools" to see what request gets submitted?

Comment: You could also look into the `nba_api` package that's actively maintained and has documented a lot of the NBA APIs. It more than likely contains the API you're trying to scrape. https://github.com/swar/nba_api

Answer (score 2):

The player data is embedded inside `<script>` element in the page. You can decode it with this example:

```py
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.nba.com/players"

data = re.search(r'({"props":.*})', requests.get(url).text).group(0)
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

df = pd.DataFrame(data["props"]["pageProps"]["players"])
print(df.head().to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | PERSON_ID | PLAYER_LAST_NAME | PLAYER_FIRST_NAME | PLAYER_SLUG | TEAM_ID | TEAM_SLUG | IS_DEFUNCT | TEAM_CITY | TEAM_NAME | TEAM_ABBREVIATION | JERSEY_NUMBER | POSITION | HEIGHT | WEIGHT | COLLEGE | COUNTRY | DRAFT_YEAR | DRAFT_ROUND | DRAFT_NUMBER | ROSTER_STATUS | FROM_YEAR | TO_YEAR | PTS | REB | AST | STATS_TIMEFRAME | PLAYER_LAST_INITIAL | HISTORIC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1630173 | Achiuwa | Precious | precious-achiuwa | 1610612761 | raptors | 0 | Toronto | Raptors | TOR | 5 | F | 6-8 | 225 | Memphis | Nigeria | 2020 | 1 | 20 | 1 | 2020 | 2021 | 9.1 | 6.5 | 1.1 | Season | A | False |
| 1 | 203500 | Adams | Steven | steven-adams | 1610612763 | grizzlies | 0 | Memphis | Grizzlies | MEM | 4 | C | 6-11 | 265 | Pittsburgh | New Zealand | 2013 | 1 | 12 | 1 | 2013 | 2021 | 6.9 | 10 | 3.4 | Season | A | False |
| 2 | 1628389 | Adebayo | Bam | bam-adebayo | 1610612748 | heat | 0 | Miami | Heat | MIA | 13 | C-F | 6-9 | 255 | Kentucky | USA | 2017 | 1 | 14 | 1 | 2017 | 2021 | 19.1 | 10.1 | 3.4 | Season | A | False |
| 3 | 1630583 | Aldama | Santi | santi-aldama | 1610612763 | grizzlies | 0 | Memphis | Grizzlies | MEM | 7 | F-C | 6-11 | 215 | Loyola-Maryland | Spain | 2021 | 1 | 30 | 1 | 2021 | 2021 | 4.1 | 2.7 | 0.7 | Season | A | False |
| 4 | 200746 | Aldridge | LaMarcus | lamarcus-aldridge | 1610612751 | nets | 0 | Brooklyn | Nets | BKN | 21 | C-F | 6-11 | 250 | Texas-Austin | USA | 2006 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2006 | 2021 | 12.9 | 5.5 | 0.9 | Season | A | False |